# Scala How to pass an array of array and boolean as a parameter?

Tags: arrays, scala

How to pass an array of (array and boolean) as a parameter?

Example:

```
val conditionalGroupBy = Array(
    Array(Array("segment","BU","SBU"), true),
    Array(Array("segment","BU"), false),
    Array(Array("segment"),false)
    )
```

Using `def myFunc(myparam:Array[Any])` works but then I have to cast since I pass `Any`, like

```
    val groupByItems = myparam(0).asInstanceOf[Array[String]]
    val shouldGroupBy= myparam(1).asInstanceOf[Boolean]
```

Is there something more specific like `Array[(Array[String],Boolean)]`?

Comment: Why don't you try exactly this: `Array[(Array[String],Boolean)]` BTW, that is an `Array` of tuples. Also, it may be worth to use `List` instead of `Array`

Comment: Okay, I will switch to Array of Tuples and try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As Luis suggested, you can slightly change types and end up with:

```
def myFunc(myparam: Array[(Array[String],Boolean)])
```

Personally, I would go for case classes:

```
case class MyClass(array: Array[String], flag: Boolean)

def myFunc(myparam: Array[MyClass])
```

Comment: Yes, unlike C#, there is not support for named tuple so I had to do myparam._1 and myparam._2. At least I don't have to cast anymore.